# people that will laugh at anything

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word or phrase for either the people who will laugh at anything or something that describes this and can be extended to be used with people?

Comment: Can you please provide context for the "hysteria"?

Comment: People with a low LQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ridibund

> <sub>[From Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ridibund)</sub>
>
> Inclined to and easily brought to laughter; happy.

---

<sub>This word [is rarely used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abderian,%20ridibund&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) so I recommend that you stick with more natural phrases like **[quick to laughter.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quick%20to%20laughter%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en)**</sub>

Comment: What a delightful word! And all I could come up with is "easily amused".

Comment: @moonstar2001 I have [a very useful tool.](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=easy+laughter)

Comment: A word that will leave the audience scurrying for a good dictionary. A word so rare that stories will be told about you. A word to flaunt your erudition... not a word for everyday use.

Comment: If you use the word **ridibund** people will laugh at you.

Answer (score 6):

You might say they would *laugh to see a pudding crawl* [[Using English.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332033/what-is-the-equivalent-for-the-danish-phrase-eat-bread-meaning-calm-down/332094#332094)]:-

> Someone who would laugh to see a pudding crawl is easily amused and
> will laugh at anything.

(See also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49976/why-does-one-laugh-to-see-a-pudding-crawl).)

Comment: In Poland it's cheese, and we have a 'tomato' game

Answer (score 3):

Abderian: [Given to laughter; inclined to foolish or incessant merriment](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Abderian).

Based on [Abdera](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Abderite)

Cachinnating is to "to laugh aloud, laugh immoderately"

Comment: The suggested adjective is not endorsed.

Comment: Superbly over-engineered, completely incomprehensible and wrong: From Wiki: *Usage notes
Ancient belief was that "the people of Abdera are fools and madmen" (stulti et insani Abderitae).[1] - nothing to do with laughing.*

Answer (score 2):

While not very common, the term **[risible](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/risible)** can mean

> able or inclined to laugh

More common is the phrase **easily amused**.

Comment: easily amused - great.

Comment: 'Risible' may be uncommon, but I'd say the sense given here is very rare.

Answer (score 1):

**giggly**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/giggly

It's often used for a just a brief state of it, but can be used to describe someone who is usually giggly.

Comment: Hello, Aidan. Please add the definition. [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/giggly)'s is probably more appropriate here, though you'd probably need OED to underscore the 'habitual' sense you correctly say is possible. Otherwise, there are a reasonable number of examples of "giggly person" on the internet, and the term is relatively unlikely to be used to describe a brief episode.