# What is the equivalent for the Danish phrase "eat bread", meaning "calm down"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation, danish

In Danish we got a good-humored phrase which goes like this:

> *Spis lige brød til*

Literally speaking it means:

> *eat bread to* or *eat some bread*

This of course makes no sense in English
in Danish the phrase means:

> Hey!, calm down, chill man, slow down and so forth

Do you have anything similar in English with the *eat bread* or *eat some bread*  included?

Comment: *Have a cookie / biscuit*?

Comment: From what I know *have a cookie/biscuit* means cheer up?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "have a cookie" - presumably it's a uniquely North American expression? [Urban Dictionary's definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Have%20a%20cookie) suggests it means something quite different to the Dutch phrase.

Comment: To your original question: No such phrase is current in the United States as far as I know (I cannot answer for other English-speaking countries). However, we do have the colloquialism, "Hold your horses!" This may do what you want.

Comment: @thb I am familiar with the expression hold your horses, still it would be q.i. if there was something close to *spis lige børd til*

Comment: @Chappo: If the cookie phrase is North American, I have never heard it as far as I recall. (I was born in and have lived nearly all my life in the U.S.)

Comment: But there is *take a chill pill*.

Comment: these are all very awesome suggestions and I am greatful for inputs. still needs some bread crumps :)

Comment: @vickyace: There is, though it is a weak expression most likely to be used by some who do not speak their own language well. One suspects that, as a colloquialism, *take a chill pill* is not firmly rooted and will fade.

Comment: *Take a breather*.

Comment: *coffee break* I want you to  *walk it off* or *take a lap*.  Too bad tobacco is on the wane, *smoke em if you got em*.

Comment: To someone who is getting over-animated in a discussion ... "Miss a beat" (sorry, no bread there).

Comment: @vickyace - Take a chill pill is definitely well used in BrEng.  I'd suggest you post it as an answer, actually.  :)

Comment: "Give us today the bread that we need"--Jesus Christ. The more common version reads, "Give us now our daily bread . . .." I like the former, because there is an element of anxiety attached to the thought about where our next meal is coming from. In Jesus' day, people did live from hand to mouth, so he taught them not to be concerned/worried/anxious/overwrought about tomorrow's bread, but to ask God for TODAY's bread, today. Perhaps your Danish phrase means, in part, "Quit your worrying and have a piece of bread. Be thankful for what you have right now, and calm down." That sort of thing. Don

Comment: There's no eating or crumbs involved, but I’ve seen [“Stop/slow down and smell the roses!”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slow%20down%20and%20smell%20the%20roses) extended to coffee so you could probably get away with extending it to anything that smells good, like: “Stop/slow down and smell the [fresh/ly baked] bread!”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a *common* phrase among the English, to my particular knowledge, but there is a fairly well known passage in the Bible which might work for your purposes. It runs as follows:

> Eat your bread with joy, and drink your wine with a merry heart.

The full passage can be found in [Ecclesiastes 9:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Ecclesiastes%209%3A7).

Comment: No one ever says this when someone is stressed out. I'd probably think they were pretty oddball if someone said that to me.

Comment: Would it be possible for someone to downvote this?

Comment: Well-known to whom? While most Americans are Christian, there are still an odd 40% who aren't. Christians don't even make up a majority in many other English-speaking countries (UK, Australia).

Answer (score 7):

You could use **take a chill pill**.

See definition at [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chill-pill)

> A notional pill taken to make a person calm down or relax.

As a verb *take a chil pill* means calm down. See [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take--a--chill--pill).

Comment: This is rude to say to someone's face, however.

Comment: @Laurel - I'm not sure that it's rude but it would imply that you thought someone was behaving a bit frantically.  Whether or not that person would take offense would probably depend on the circumstance and the behavior.  I'm sure that among certain groups it could even be said good-naturedly much like *eat some bread*.

Answer (score 2):

This might be regional in application, but consider the invitation, "*Cuppa tea?*".

- In times of crisis, there is nothing like a nice soothing cup of tea. [- dailymail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-3115689/Put-kettle-cup-tea-really-best-remedy-stress-caffeine-soothing-effect.html)
- The findings reveal that even a single cup of tea can significantly reduce anxiety levels after suffering a stressful experience – and in some cases, make people calmer than they were before. [- The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/6015821/A-cup-of-tea-really-can-help-reduce-stress-at-times-of-crisis-claim-scientists.html)

It's a colloquialism, which [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cuppa%20Tea) helpfully expands to

> Cup of Tea. One of the best drinks ever. Better than coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Have a KitKat?

(From the "Have a break - have a KitKat" slogan for the KitKat chocolate bars.)

Comment: This isn't bad actually, it's quite clever but I don't know if our American friends are familiar with the tagline and if they have the same commercial. And I don't know if the tagline has changed recently.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the ad is fairly universal.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Which one is the tag line you are referring to? We get Kit Kat ads in the US (the song is what comes to mind first), but there may be different emphasis on different slogans, so I'm not sure what exactly the tag line you're talking about.

Comment: Though the intention of the phrase in the ad is to have a similar effect as the Danish system, do native English speakers actually _use_ the phrase for the effect?

Comment: This brings up an interesting general language question. THere are many examples of company names becoming generic vocab items (kleenex, xerox, biro, google). But have any _phrases_ from companies/advertisements become generic. 'Think Different', 'Calgon Take Me Away', 'I'm Loving It'. Nobody says those as generics.

Comment: Being half English and having lived 17+ years in England, I reserve the right to suggest new expressions! But I leave it to the voters to decide whether it makes enough sense to English speakers other than me, of course.